# Helm Go Template combine existing values with external json file

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have this ConfigMap and I need to combine values with an external json file

```
data:
  variables.json: |
    { "image_tags" : {
        "app1": "{{ .Values.app1.tag }}",
        "app2": "{{ .Values.app2.tag }}"
       }
    }
```

And I have this external messages.json file:

```
"messages" : {
   "msg1" : "abc",
   "msg2" : "def",
   "msg3" : "hij"
}
```

The result should look like this:

```
data:
  variables.json: |
    { "image_tags" : {
        "app1": "{{ .Values.app1.tag }}",
        "app2": "{{ .Values.app2.tag }}"
       },
      "messages" : {
         "msg1" : "abc",
         "msg2" : "def",
         "msg3" : "hij"
      }
    }
```

How do I do that in helm chart?

Comment: Is the first block an existing ConfigMap, or is it something that your chart creates?

Comment: It is an existing block.